# Method Swizzle encodeWithCoder/initWithCoder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

We're working on an app that saves a lot of stuff in to Core Data. The stuff it saves is mainly `NSDate` `NSNumber` & `NSString` but it also saves many images and videos as `NSData`. I'm trying to change it so that these files are instead saved to local storage and a file name is saved in core data instead, then we just load it up from the local storage, hopefully saving time when accessing core data and making it a bit more stable.

After discussing it, we thought it would be easiest to override encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder so that we can just intercept the calls to save the data and save them on the file system instead. Then I found out that NSData is actually a part of a class cluster and so overriding the functions is harder then it seems.

So then I read about method swizzling where you can just swap one implementation for another. I Googled around and found [this](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling), and also found a post on Stack Overflow saying to use that article, but it didn't really help me and I'm still non the wiser on how I would do what I need.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or give me some of their own pointers on how I would do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Don't method swizzle these -- trust me :)

If you want to save out as described, place that implementation in your class' implementation of the archiving methods (not a subclass, not a swizzle, but the class that contains these objects).

Comment: So just a wrapper that contains an NSData that handles the saving? I thought about this but was hoping for a more elegant solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Luke Up a bit. I was referring to a *container* class of the images, movies, etc - not a pure foundation type wrapper.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. So create my own array that stores all the `NSData`s? The problem is that they're stored all over the place in many core data entity files. Is there a simpler way to just add my functionality to encodeWithCoder etc?

Comment: @Luke i am referring to the container as the the object which represents these assets/instances, e.g.: `@interface MONMediaContainer : LEBaseClass < NSCoding >

@property (blah) NSData * data;
@property (blah) NSNumber * number;
@property (blah) NSString * string;

@end

@implementation MONMediaContainer

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)pCoder
{
 // write members to disk
 // save the location in pCoder
}`